Notifications are silent in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Sound works fine everywhere else such as Youtube, Spotify, but notifications don't make sound. I have tested Google Chrome and Terminal notifcations.

Do Not Disturb is off
In Settings > Sound > Volume Levels > Systems Sounds are the only item, and set to max
Settings > Sound > Alert sound is set to default. Clicking this option plays the sound.
Terminal command notify-send foo bar creates the notification but no sound
Terminal command zenity --notification --text "Foo bar" creates the notification but no sound
A low battery notifications does make a sound.

Help appreciated
